# android app logging in on android 4.0.3 but not on android 6.1

Tags: php, android

i developed a simple app using android 4.0.3. The problem im having is the login screen. It is logging in using android 4.0.3 version but when i install it on android 6.1 it refuses to login in. Im failing to see where the problem lies.

heres is the source code for the login screen. Its just showing an error saying check your connection settings of which that is an error message i provided

```
public class LoginForm extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //EditText editTextUserName,editTextPassword;
    CardView cardView;
    FButton btnCallAndRegister;
    FButton loginButton;
    FButton btnSms;
    EditText edtUserName;


    private ProgressDialog mProgress;


    String login_url = "https://volleycrud.000webhostapp.com/churchapp/logger.php";
    String gotUserName;
   // ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_form);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(LoginForm.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        mProgress.setTitle("Processing...");
        mProgress.setMessage("Logging in Please wait...");
        mProgress.setCancelable(false);
        mProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
        loginButton = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        edtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        btnCallAndRegister = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterCall);
        btnSms = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.smsButton);

        //get the data as json from the server for the branch name

        android.view.animation.Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.swing_up_left);
        cardView.setAnimation(animation);

        btnSms.setOnClickListener(this);


        btnCallAndRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0772325760"));

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginForm.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }

                startActivity(callIntent);

            }

        });


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(edtUserName.getText().equals("")){


                    CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                            .setTitle("Error")
                            .setMessage("Please enter a username")
                            .show();


                }

                else {
                    mProgress.show();
                    gotUserName = edtUserName.getText().toString();
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginForm.this);
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            if (response.trim().equals("success")) {

                                mProgress.hide();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();


                            } else {

                                CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                                        .setTitle("Error")
                                        .setMessage("Please check your username")
                                        .show();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                                    .setTitle("Error")
                                    .setMessage("Check Your Connection Settings")
                                    .show();
                            Log.i("My error", "" + error);
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("username", gotUserName);
                            return map;
                        }
                    };

                    queue.add(request);
                }

                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){


            case R.id.smsButton:


                AlertDialog dialogSms = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginForm.this).create();
                dialogSms.setTitle("Send Us A Message");
                dialogSms.setIcon(R.drawable.uficlogo);

                final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(LoginForm.this);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                final EditText order = new EditText(this);
                order.setHintTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                order.setHint("Enter your Message");

                layout.addView(order);
            dialogSms.setView(layout);

            dialogSms.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Send SMS",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String message = order.getText().toString();

                            if (!message.equals("")) {

                                sendMySms(message);

                            } else {

                                CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                                        .setTitle("Error")
                                        .setMessage("Message Not Sent")
                                        .show();

                            }

                        }

                        private void sendMySms(String message) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String number = "0772 325 760".trim();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    LoginForm.class);
                            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                    getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
                            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, pi,
                                    null);

                            CookieBar.build(LoginForm.this)
                                    .setTitle("Success")
                                    .setMessage("Message Sent")
                                    .show();

                        }

                    });

            dialogSms.show();


            break;

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you given `runtime` permission?

If no then give all the necessary permissions to enable the app to fire a HTTP request.

To set `runtime` permission, you can go through:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.